# Aura:Iteration creating child components and radio buttons. I want to access the aura:id of both child component and radio button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="map"  type="map" />  
     <aura:attribute name = "lstOfMapKeys" type="list"/>
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

        <!--Iterate the mapEntry Component.-->
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfMapKeys}" var="key" indexVar="rowCnt" > 
          <c:childCmp map="{!v.map}" key="{!key}" />
           <div  >  
               <lightning:input label="Yes" name="selectEitherOne" type="radio"  aura:id="{!'index'+rowCnt}" onchange="{!c.hasId}"/>
               <lightning:input label="No" name="selectEitherOne" type="radio" aura:id="{!'index2'+rowCnt}" value="No"/>
               <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectEitherOne == true}">
                   <lightning:input label="Please enter Text" aura:id="{!'indexYes'+key}"/>
               </aura:if>
           </div>
       </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: You can't use aura:id the way you're trying to. Please read the answer to [my question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/221892) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Now i am getting same indexVar id for child and radio buttons. How do i check user clicked on which radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Aura id's cannot be dynamically incremented/changed in aura:iterations - not supported.

> 2.- How do i check user clicked on which radio button?

as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/documentation):

> You can retrieve the button that's clicked by using event.getSource().
>   For example, to retrieve the label on the button, use
>   event.getSource().get("v.label").

you can also refer to [Which Button Was Pressed?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm)