# How can I set focus on a lightning:input, generated inside a aura:iteration, from controller method triggered by another element's event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I have an Aura component with an `aura:iteration` that each iteration generates a `lightning:formattedNumber`, a hidden `lightning:input` (both for the same field), and a `lightning:buttonIcon` that calls a controller method that hides the first and shows the second one.

I want to show and **focus** the `lightning:input` after I click the button, but I'm not able to use the `.focus()` method, because I can't get the component with `.find()`, since It seems I can't dynamically set `aura:id`.

Also, I tried to use a parent `span` with an `id` to access the `input` tag generated by the `lightning:input` with something like `document.querySelector('#myDynamicIdValue input')`, but it returns only `null`.

How could I focus this input?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Code shouldn't've be presented as images and answers don't go in questions. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. Your information can be found in the [revision history](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/336360/revisions) if you care to post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an iteration value to each row, then use that to figure out which input to focus.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" indexVar="index">
  <div class="..." data-index="{!index}">
    ...
    <lightning:input aura:id="itemInput" ... />
```

Then, for your click handler:

```
onShowInlineEdit: function(component, event, helper) {
  let index = parseInt(event.target.closest("[data-index]").dataset.index);
  let inputs = component.find("itemInput");
  inputs[index].focus();
}
```

This is essentially a version of my [own problem that I had](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/221892/2984).

Comment: I used this idea of getting the list of inputs, but modified a little bit to filter by a string Id. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a component to contain the markup inside of aura:iteration.

This way there will be only one instance of lightning:input per inner component, thus the aura:id won't need to be dynamic and you can use component.find() to locate the lightning:input.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's seems a clean solution. As this UI grows, I'll eventually ending doing this, to organize better the things.