# Lightning component - how to action on the change event of a input field within a list

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am having a list of inputfield in lightning component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.releaseScheduleList}" var="rs">
    <ui:inputDate value="{!rs.startDate}" change="{!c.startDateChange}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

So based on the change of the start date value I need to action based on which line has been updated and which value has it changed to be.

However, when I do

```
startDateChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.value"));
}
```

It doesn't seem to work well as component is not able to grab the value. If I apply `aura:id` to each `ui:inputDate` like:

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="{!rs.Id}" value="{!rs.startDate}" change="{!c.startDateChange}"/>
```

I find it a bit struggling to find the related Id as well. So in this situation, what is the best approach to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions that I found by trial and error (and help from the Ohana, of course!).

The first problem you have is that [aura:id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm) ...

> doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal string values to aura:id.

Second, I had an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TujtQAC), and eventually, I ended up asking [two](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221892) different [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212806).

Ultimately, I came up with two solutions, one if you need to support IE 11, and the one provided to me if you don't.

## IE 11+

```
<span data-record-id="{!rs.Id}" onchange="{!c.startDateChange}">
  <ui:inputDate value="{!rs.startDate}" />
</span>
```

---

```
var recordId = event.target.dataset.recordId;
```

---

## Standards-Compliant Browsers

```
<!-- note: this is preferred; some components don't propagate changes -->
<span data-record-id="{!rs.Id}">
  <ui:inputDate value="{!rs.startDate}" onchange="{!c.startDateChange}" />
</span>
```

---

```
var recordId = event.target.closest("[data-record-id]").dataset.recordId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not get aura:id in aura:iteration.you could use input tag replace ui: tag.and then add attribute id="{!rs.Id}" like this `<input id="{!rs.Id}" change="{!c.startDateChange}" type="date"/>.`